# How to use spread function to get an equivalent result to cast()

Tags: r, casting, reshape, tidyr, spread

I have been informed that the `reshape` package has not been actively maintained for a long long while; also, i have noticed that the number coming out from the `cast()` function is not accurate in my case, so now I am looking into the `spread()` function in `tidyr` package. I have gone through a lot of examples and I still don't get how to use it. Can anyone please help explain that in my case?

My data is consisted of multiple variables, of which **Grade**, **Date**, and **Revenue** are the 3 variables I want to reshape as another data frame.

Originally, I was trying to do

```
cast(mydata, Grade ~ Date, value= "Revenue", sum)
```

to see how much does every grade earn in total.

The result comes out in a desired format as followed, but the numbers are completely incorrect...

```
> head(mydata)
                     Grade    001.2020 1. Period 2020 002.2020 2. Period 2020 003.2020 3. Period 2020 004.2020 4. Period 2020
1 5160     Brne                              0                    3773                       0                       0
2 5305     Vleipner                     871751                  872116                  790616                 1086088
3 5315     Digor                        282535                  232953                  368555                  218094
4 5329     Yverker 21                   327740                  308353                  246029                  354357
5 5337     Hanadis 8 S                  167158                  185662                  202147                  135868
6 5339     NADIS 4                      496648                  403006                  693280                  657806
>
```

As suggested, the result of dput(head(mydata)) is attached below,

```
> dput(head(mydata))
structure(list(Quality = structure(1:6, .Label = c("rne", 
"eipner", "gor", "verker 21", 
"nadis 8 S", "xtra Supe", 
"dis 10", "die", "almax", 
"dar 1", "Supre", 
"Mic", "Vik", 
"TIG", "var", "ormvar", 
"olmax", "imax", "imax SR"), class = "factor"), `001.2020 1. Period 2020` = c(0, 
871751, 282535, 327740, 167158, 496648), `002.2020 2. Period 2020` = c(3773, 
872116, 232953, 308353, 185662, 403006), `003.2020 3. Period 2020` = c(0, 
790616, 368555, 246029, 202147, 693280), `004.2020 4. Period 2020` = c(0, 
1086088, 218094, 354357, 135868, 657806)), idvars = "Grade", rdimnames = list(
    structure(list(Grade = structure(1:47, .Label = c("rne", 
"eipner", "gor", "verker 21", "nadis 8 S", "xtra Supe", 
"dis 10", "die", "almax", 
"dar 1", "Supre", 
"Mic", "Vik", 
"TIG", "var", "ormvar", 
"olmax", "imax", "imax SR"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("rne", 
"eipner", "gor", "verker 21", 
"nadis 8 S", "xtra Supe", 
"dis 10", "die", "almax", 
"dar 1", "Supre", 
"Mic", "Vik", 
"TIG", "var", "ormvar", 
"olmax", "imax", "imax SR"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        Period.year = structure(1:4, .Label = c("001.2020 1. Period 2020", 
        "002.2020 2. Period 2020", "003.2020 3. Period 2020", 
        "004.2020 4. Period 2020"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("001.2020 1. Period 2020", 
    "002.2020 2. Period 2020", "003.2020 3. Period 2020", "004.2020 4. Period 2020"
    ), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("cast_df", 
"data.frame"))
>
```

Are the numbers supposed to be cleansed before `cast()`? If so, how so?

If not, then is `spread()` meant to do the same? If so, how to make the magic happen?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: @RonakShah Please see the updated content, i have attached the desired format.

Comment: please use `dput(head(mydata))` to provide example data. it makes things much easier.

Comment: It sounds like your data was already in long format, with no need to `cast` or `spread`. Perhaps try `library(dplyr); mydata %>% group_by(Grade) %>% summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue))`

Comment: @Brian I thought `cast` is to transfer a long format into a wide one; didn't know that `cast` is used for a long format...

Comment: @mmkuchi can you post `head(your_original_data)`? It's not clear what format it's in before you're trying to convert from long to wide.